# В сети появляются телефоны

Tags: windows, роутер

На основном компьютере установлена ОС *Windows 10*, по *Wi Fi* подключены 2 ноутбука с ОС *Windows 7*.

В проводнике на основном компьютере, щелкнув внизу в левой колонке по пункту *Сеть*, справа открываются сетевые подключения. В верху отображен мой компьютер, с подключенными моими компьютерами, ниже маршрутизатор и ниже какие-то телефоны. На других компьютерах телефоны не отображаются. Если подключиться к сети напрямую, минуя маршрутизатор, то телефоны не отображаются. Если зайти в настройки маршрутизатора, то там, где отображаются подключения эти телефоны также не отображаются. Таким образом, эти телефоны видны только на моем компьютере и, похоже, только в ОС *Windows 10*.

Тем не менее, думаю, что эти телефоны подключены незаконно, по крайней мере я их не подключал. Как их убрать и предотвратить подобные несанкционированные подключения?

Пароль менял - не помогло. Маршрутизатор *NetGear N150 WNR1000v2h2*
Спасибо.

Answer (score -2):

Ответ похоже здесь. Нужно отключить WPS в роутере.
http://forum.ru-board.com/topic.cgi?forum=62&topic=26950

Comment: Пожалуйста давайте более подробные ответы

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: ответ по ссылке выше помог отключением WPS